# How to create a user for my sharepoint 2010 site without active directory

Tags: 2010, user-accounts

I am building a sharepoint site for a college department I work for. Our sharepoint site is linked to the active directory of the school so it seems like I can only add users that are in the active directory.

I would like to create a test user so I can test the permissions that I've set up.

How do I go about doing that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request a test domain account be created.  The IT department should end up creating a domain account with no real permissions to access anything that you can use for testing.  At least they will here at our university.

Comment: There's no way to do it locally just for our sharepoint site?

Comment: No, if the environment is set up to use AD as the authentication source, then you need another AD account or someone willing to be a guinea pig for you.

Comment: Thank you for answering my questions Eric!
From another Eric as well =D
I just had this very question come up in a meeting today.